# 2 submit buttons on form - need one to open a new window

Tags: php, submit, action

Using a form with a blank action - action="".

I have 2 buttons on the form that do different things.  one to submit/save the info, the other to open an output sheet:

```
<input type="submit" name="SubmitSave" id="SubmitSave" value="Submit / Save" onClick="this.form.action='PA_Monitorcall.php'; this.form.submit()" />

<input type="submit" name="EmailDetails" id="EmailDetails" value="Email" onClick="this.form.action='OutputSheetPA.php'; this.form.submit()" />
```

I need the output sheet to open in a new window, but can't have this in the form header details, it will need to go in the code for the button above.  Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onClick event of both submit buttons, call a javascript function, which would toggle the 'target' attribute of the form tag to '_blank' or '_parent'/''.
with this new value for 'target' attribute your post would be submitted in a new window/tab

```
<form target="" action="" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Same Window" onClick="ChangeTarget('same')" />
 <input type="submit" value="New Window" onClick="ChangeTarget('new')" />
</form>

function ChangeTarget(loc) {
 if(loc=="new") {
  document.getElementById('form_id').target="_blank";
 } else {
  document.getElementById('form_id').target="";
 }
}
```

Comment: was just writing that. It should also remove it again afterwards otherwise button 1 will now do the same. OR get button1 to remove it too

Comment: If you preview (open another window) the form will still have target="_blank" on original page (still open). You only specified that the onclick function would change the target for __second__ button, not both. Yours is the right answer, just needs polishing :)

Comment: I think this will be the way to go to be honest, can you help me out with the code?  is it along the lines of document.gelElementByID?

Comment: @Waygood it definitely needs some polishing, i would edit the answer

Comment: @Chris i have added the solution, editing the answer above, please make necessary changes, as this is not a tested code

Comment: @SankalpShekhar Thanks mate, can I include that 'ChangeTarget' function along with the onClick="this.form.action='OutputSheetPA.php'; this.form.submit()" I already have on the buttons? just tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @Chris, I assumed, the buttons in questions are Submit buttons, so you don't need to call `this.form.submit()`

Anyways, you can call the provided function `changeTarget` before form submit event

Comment: @SankalpShekharHey man, thanks very much, got it all working as intended.  Awesome, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="button"` instead. Your `onClick` already calls submit, so you don't need them to be `submit` inputs.

Comment: if the button action isn't a `submit`, don't use `type='submit'`!

Answer (score -1):

You can name the two inputs with the same name and then check the value of that inputs.

```
<form action="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="SubmitSave" value="Submit / Save" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="EmailDetails" value="Email" /></form>
</form>
```

And in the php file:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit / Save')
    // save the form input
elseif ($_POST['submit'] == 'Email')
    // do other stuff
...
```

Comment: The aim is something like a preview. Post to new window was specified